# Distribution density

Tags: probability-theory

Can you please tell me how you can solve this? Where can I see examples or something like.

The distribution density of the random variable $\xi$ is given ($\alpha$, $\beta$ are known and positive):
$$f(x) = H \exp\left\{-\frac{|x-\alpha|}{\beta}\right\}$$

Find the constant $H$ and $Mξ$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use two properties of [probability density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function): $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x) dx = 1$ and $M\xi = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}x f(x) dx$.
After calculating these integrals you will get $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x) dx = H\cdot 2\beta$, so $H = \frac{1}{2\beta}$ and $M\xi = \alpha$.

Also, given function is the probability density function of [Laplace distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_distribution).